# Backbone.js: How do I filter a collection of objects by an array of model IDs?

Tags: javascript, collections, filter, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've got a `Backbone.Collection` full of models; let's say that model is `Car`. This collection is a great, big list of `Cars`. I want to be able to have a few specific car IDs selected from a list, and then be able to get just those selected car objects out of this collection.

My code block below isn't working; I'm sure there's a way to do this with Backbone.js/Underscore.js… I'm pretty fresh to Backbone/Underscore, too.

```
CarList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Car,
    filterWithIds: function(ids) {
        return this.filter(function(aCar) { return _.contains(ids, car.id); }
    }
});
```

Any pointers?

Comment: The anonymous function passed to `this.filter` is missing a return statement. Unlike some other languages (e.g., Ruby) JavaScript does not use the last expression in a function as a default return value. (Also, the line assigning `this` to `coll` is redundant.)

Comment: You're right, Niall… I was translating my code from CoffeeScript by eyeballing it and I left that out; and in simplifying my code, I accidentally left that redundant line in. I've fixed my code example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, I think I've got it. It's close to my original code block, but the updated `filterWithIds` function is here.

```
filterWithIds: function(ids) {
    return _(this.models.filter(function(c) { return _.contains(ids, c.id); }));
}
```

For those following along in CoffeeScript (I am), here's the CoffeeScript version.

```
filterWithIds: (ids) -> _(@models.filter (c) -> _.contains ids, c.id)
```

It's my answer; any code smell?

Comment: Instead of using include, you might try the condition `c.id in ids` which coffeescript turns into a for loop checking each id against c.id.

Comment: Since this answer was posted, `include` was renamed to `contains`.